# How Can I bundle a simple node.js application

Tags: amazon-managed-blockchain

I am working with hyperledger-fabric on amazon managed blockchain. There I have written the chaincode with node.js. The problem is, the dependencies I'm using is not supported in amazon managed blockchain's peer. That's why I need to bundle my chaincode with the node modules. How can I do tha?

Answer (score 4):

Here are steps for bundling Node.js chaincode with external dependencies on Amazon Managed Blockchain Hyperledger Fabric 2.2 networks:

**Why bundling is needed:**
Due to stringent security requirements, peer nodes in Amazon Managed Blockchain do not have access to the open internet. This means that peer nodes cannot download external dependencies at runtime when building/executing chaincode. If you suspect missing node_modules/ are responsible for errors in your chaincode, you can verify this by viewing Chaincode logs in Amazon CloudWatch, where reference to missing node_modules / dependencies will be clearly evident.

**How to bundle dependencies**
First, navigate to the root directory of the chaincode you wish to deploy. Your *package.json* file should be present in this directory. From this directory, run `npm i` to install node_modules. Then, move those node_modules to a new directory -- Example:

```bash
mv node_modules/ lib
```

Moving the dependencies to `lib/` will allow you to package the installed NPM packages (dependencies) in the chaincode *tar.gz* file in the following steps. Because the node_modules are stored in `lib/`, the Node.js start script in `package.json` has been modified slightly to tell the container environment that runs the chaincode where to find the dependencies at runtime: `"start": "NODE_PATH=lib node <entrypoint filename>.js"`

```
{
  "name": "chaincode",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_PATH=lib mocha *_test.js",
    "start": "NODE_PATH=lib node products.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "fabric-shim": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@theledger/fabric-mock-stub": "^2.0.3",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
    "chai-datetime": "^1.6.0",
    "moment": "^2.25.3"
  }
}
```

With the node_modules bundled in `lib/` and the start script for the chaincode modified to point to those node_modules, one can now package, install, approve and commit this chaincode as normal using the Chaincode Lifecycle commands.

Comment: I guess the Amazon Managed Blockchain docs on `Getting Started` tab could make use of your answer on `Step 7: Run Chaincode` subtab. Also, this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/managed-blockchain/latest/hyperledger-fabric-dev/managed-blockchain-hyperledger-develop-chaincode.html could be included somewhere more explicitly in this same step. Anyway, thank you for your help and time.

Comment: I will submit that as feedback to the AWS documentation team. Thank you. If this answer solved your issue, please do accept it as the answer so others may find it.

Comment: unfortunately I'm not the OP. But your answer definitely helped me.

Comment: This was the best answer I have read online, easy and simple to understand